# Problem in packaging Failed! ureal Engine android project

Tags: android

Problem when Package Unreal project for Android Device

UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): * What went wrong:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)):   [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)):   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)):   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): * Try:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Users\GAURAV\Documents\Unreal Projects\EndlessRunner\Intermediate/Android/APK\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)):        (see C:\Users\GAURAV\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.20\Log.txt for full exception trace)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
LogSlate: FSceneViewport::OnFocusLost() reason 2

Comment: please format your question

Comment: hi bro, please help me to get out this error, i am stuck on this error since 10 days and i did not get any solution for this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ATC)): Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager

You need to make sure the sdk and ndk are set properly. https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/how-to-set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk-for-your-unreal-engine-development-environment/

THEN, go to the project settings, and under android there are a couple of red banners. you need to click the button there to accept stuff and enable them.

(You might need Java JDK 8 (yes 8) and .net 5 and .net 3.1 (yes, required, both. the desktop version is fine, otherwise the runtime))